# React setState renders three times

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, render, setstate

guys, I am using React and have one question:
I am making an array of data from the json, and when I am doing setState in the constructor it renders three times. First and second times I am getting an empty array and on the third time I am getting an array with data, that I need.
So, the question is, how to get that data only from the third time rendering, or how to optimize the method, that I am using?

here is my constructor(props) {

```
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        q: '',
        a: '',
        array: [],
    };

    var that = this;
    var q = [];
    var a = [];
    var r = [];
    var arr = [];

    axios.get('/api/sample/data.json')
        .then(function (response) {
            var example = response.data.attributes.responses;
            var q = that.props.first_object.map((q) => {
                q.push({
                    q: q.text
                })
            })
            var responses = example.map((res) => {
                if (res.string_value){
                    a.push({
                        a: res.string_value,
                        q: res.q
                    })
                }
                else if (res.text_value){
                    a.push({
                        a: res.text_value,
                        q: res.q,
                    })
                }
                else if (res.string_value == null || res.string_value == '' || res.text_value == null){
                    a.push({
                        a: res.a,
                        q: res.q
                    })
                }
            })
            for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
                var _q = q[i].q;
                var _a = '';
                var _q= '';
                for(var j = 0; j < a.length; j++){
                    if (_q == a[j].q){
                        _a = a[j].a
                        break
                    }
                }
                var username = that.props.user.map((u) => {
                    if (response.data.attributes.user_id == u.user_id){
                        return u.first_name + ' ' + u.last_name
                    }
                })
                var user = ''
                for (var u = 0; u < username.length; u++) {
                    if (username[u] !== undefined) {
                        user = username[u]
                        break
                    }
                }
                r[0] = user
                r.push(_q)
                r.push(_a)
            }
            var name = r[0];
            for (var b = 1; b < r.length; b+=2) {
                arr.push([r[0],r[b],r[b+1]])
            }
            that.setState({array: arr})
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

[first and second renderings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE3vu.png)

[third rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LFeb.png)

Comment: Your app renders twice because a `state` or `props` changes somewhere. From the code you provide, you are only mutating the `state` once, so it seems unlikely that there's any problem with that code. The render is probably triggered twice somewhere else, before it triggers here. Try logging something to your console right before your `setState` - does the log also print 3 times, or just once?

Comment: console.log prints only on the last render. right before the correct array.

Comment: Okay, that would mean that the code you provided doesn't trigger the render 3 times, but only once. The problem must be elsewhere in your code. Try following the chain *before* your XHR request. Also, instead of `console.log` try using `debugger`.